# What's the best practices for storing visits?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

I would like to save visits in a table. I am using MySQL but I am not sure how I should save the visits as the records may increase considerably and this might cause performance issues and I am also worried about MySQL limitations (how many records it can handle, etc).

As far as I know, I could do this in two different ways:

**First way:**

Creating a record for each visit

| id | visitor_ip |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 111111111 |
| 2 | 111111111 |
| 3 | 111111112 |

**Second way:**

I could create a record and update/increment the `number_of_visits` field each visit

| id | number_of_visits | visitor_ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 111111111 |
| 2 | 1 | 111111112 |

**So my question is:**

Is there any real difference? There will be a significant performance issue if I choose one approach over another seeing as the number of records in the first approach might be considerably more than the second one?

Comment: Your second approach doesn't store _visits_, it stores _aggregate counts_ of visits; so, what do you actually want/need to store?

Comment: Well, you are right, sorry. What I need is that I need to save records or aggregate counts, as you said, in order to show reports, but I started wondering how bad it could get if there are many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to store aggregates, then storing those is a good idea.

As with aggregates, the `visitor_ip` is going to be unique, we may as well make that the primary key.

In MariaDB-10.5 or later you can use the [inet6 type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6/):

```
CREATE TABLE visits (ip inet6 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                     number_of_visits int NOT NULL);
```

And update using IPv4 mapped addresses if needed:

```
INSERT INTO visits
VALUES ('::127.0.0.1',1) ON duplicate KEY
UPDATE number_of_visits=number_of_visits+1
```

ref: [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=83638d0bc1124f60423a3e61eaa4798b)

If using an older MariaDB version or MySQL, `varbinary(16)` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542011/most-efficient-way-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql#2542021):

```
CREATE TABLE visits (ip varbinary(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                    number_of_visits int NOT NULL)
```

insert with:

```
INSERT INTO visits
VALUES (INET6_ATON('127.0.0.1'),1) ON duplicate KEY
UPDATE number_of_visits=number_of_visits+1
```

And retrieve with:

```
select INET6_NTOA(ip), number_of_visits from visits
```

ref: [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=54201bcd9ae4dfefa9b920e171e93c99)

Both examples take IPv6 addresses.